# How to get an inheritance tree from AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using python's ast module to display a class inheritance tree.

I defined a `visit_ClassDef(self, node)` function for an `ast.NodeVisitor`, and iterate through `node.bases`.

However, I've been unable to get the name of the base classes as a string. 
So far, I've tried `base.value` and `base.name`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're *probably* looking for the `id` attribute:

```
>>> import ast
>>> class Visit(ast.NodeVisitor):
...     def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
...         print [n.id for n in node.bases]
... 
>>> text = open('test.py').read()
>>> tree = ast.parse(text)
>>> Visit().visit(tree)
['Foo', 'Baz']
```

Here's `test.py`:

```
class Bar(Foo,Baz):
    pass
```

The documentation on this one is pretty tough to grok, but you can see that `bases` is a list of `expr` objects.  Now it can really be any expression.  You could have a function call in there:

```
class Bar(FooFactory(),BazFactory()): pass
```

and that is completely valid python.  However, the *typical* case is that you just have **identifiers** (class names) which are nothing more than `Name` expressions.  You can get the identifier's "name" as a string from the `id` attribute.

Comment: For me, `n.id` gives an error in Python v2.7 and Python v3.4. `[n.attr for n in node.bases]` seems to do the trick though.

Comment: This will only print the direct base classes (not deeper derived than 1 level down); how can I access the true inheritance tree?

Comment: note this will not list all inheritance tree - only the superclasses. If `Foo` subclasseses `Art` another then `Art` would not be included